# Error on submitting Checkbox value in ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

This is in file: **DrinkOrder.asp**

```
<form action="DrinkResult.asp" method="post">
    Drink: 
    <select name="drink">
        <option>Coffee</option>
        <option>Tea</option>
        <option>Hot Chocolate</option>
    </select>
    <p/>
    Sugar: 
    <input type="radio" name="sugar" value="1"> 1
    <input type="radio" name="sugar" value="2"> 2
    <input type="radio" name="sugar" value="3"> 3
    <p/>
    Milk: <input type="checkbox" name="milk">
    <p/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"><input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

This is in file: **DrinkResult.asp**

```
<%@language="Javascript"%>
<%
    function milkOn(form){
        var with = "";

        if(form == "1") { with = "With milk"; }
        else { with = "No milk"; }

        return with;
    }
%>

<%=("<table border=\"1\">")%>
    <%=("<tr><th><i>Drink:</i></th>" + "<td> " + (Request.Form("drink")) + "</td>")%>
    <%=("<tr><th><i>Sugar:</i></th>" + "<td> " + (Request.Form("sugar")) + "</td>")%>
    <%=("<tr><th><i>Milk:</i></th>" + "<td>" + (milkOn(Request.Form("milk"))) + "</td>")%>
<%=("</table>")%>
```

After submitting form from DrinkOrder.asp to DrinkResult.asp, I received an error which clearly I don't know how to fix it.

After a few modification I made to detect the error location, I'm pretty sure it is located at **milkOn(Request.Form("milk"))** in file DrinkResult.asp because when I remove the statement, the result shows up.

What's wrong with my code here?

Comment: (milkOn(Request.Form("milk"))) cannot be displayed. so it shows an error for the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if(form == "1")
```

to

```
if(form == "on")
```

otherwise the code seems to test fine for me.

Comment: i knew it had to do with that but i didn't know it was "on" (the value for a checked checkbox). I learn something new everyday. +1

Comment: The other option is to set the value of the milk checkbox to "1".  With no value, "on" is submitted when a checkbox is checked.